# How to convert url array query to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an URL with query params like this:

```
myLocalSite/?attributes%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=customer_property_number&attributes%5B0%5D%5Bop%5D=equal&attributes%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=12&attributes%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=feedback_tags&attributes%5B1%5D%5Bop%5D=in&attributes%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=test+1%2Cwww
```

after JSON parsing it convert into next structure

```
{
    attributes[0][name]: "customer_property_number"
    attributes[0][op]: "equal"
    attributes[0][value]: "12"
    attributes[1][name]: "feedback_tags"
    attributes[1][op]: "in"
    attributes[1][value]: "test 1,www"
}
```

In the end, I need an array that look like this:

```
attributes = [
  {
    name: 'customer_property_number',
    op: 'equal',
    value: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'feedback_tags',
    op: 'in',
    value: 'test 1, www',
  },
]
```

Now does anyone know how I can then put these items into attributes array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach using `URLSearchParams` and going over each search param, parse and push to array of objects.

```js
var sp = new URLSearchParams(
  "myLocalSite/?attributes%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=customer_property_number&attributes%5B0%5D%5Bop%5D=equal&attributes%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=12&attributes%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=feedback_tags&attributes%5B1%5D%5Bop%5D=in&attributes%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=test+1%2Cwww"
);

var attributes = [];
for (entry of sp) {
  const [attr, value] = entry;
  const [index, key] = attr
    .split("[")
    .filter(x => x.includes("]"))
    .map(x => x.slice(0, -1));
  if (!attributes[Number(index)]) {
    attributes[Number(index)] = {};
  }
  attributes[Number(index)][key] = value;
}

console.log(attributes);
```